# Python how to split values some are with spaces

Tags: python, split

Need help to split below sentence and convert it to dictionary key values

```
[score=2 last=19 delay=5 distance=10k 2 events name=Denis John P place=New York]
```

dict results should be:

```
"Event": {
 "score": "2",
  "last": "19",
  "delay": "5",
  "distance": "10k 2 events",
  "name": "Denis John",
  "place": "New York",
 }
```

I am not able to figure it out the solution,tried a lot with re but failed to split something=something, somthing=something space something using the delimiter '='

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Is that supposed to be a string? `"score=2 last=19 ..."`

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: you can use a regualr expression, something like `r"([^\s]+)=([^=]+)\s"`

Comment: Shouldn't `name` be `Denis John P`?

Answer (score 0):

This solution isn't perfect.  It requires each value to end with a space, which it discards.  I solve this by just adding a space to the end of the string and then stripping each value.

```
import re
s = "score=2 last=19 delay=5 distance=10k 2 events name=Denis John P place=New York"
s = s + ' ' 
res = re.findall(r"([^\s]+)=([^=]+)\s", s)
res = [(a, b.strip()) for (a,b) in res]
d = {"Events": dict(res)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
s = '[score=2 last=19 delay=5 distance=10k 2 events name=Denis John P place=New York]'
l = s[1:-1].split('=')
data = {}
while len(l) > 0:
    val = l.pop()
    if len(l) > 1:
        head,key = l.pop().rsplit (maxsplit=1)
        l.append (head)
    else:
        key = l.pop()
    data[key] = val

from pprint import pprint
pprint (data)
```

Outputs:

```
{'delay': '5',
 'distance': '10k 2 events',
 'last': '19',
 'name': 'Denis John P',
 'place': 'New York',
 'score': '2'}
```

Comment: @Aditya Glad to help. In return you could accept and/or upvote my answer.